# Overlaying edit box control over OpenGL pane

Tags: opengl

I have a large OpenGL canvas in a Visual C++ MFC application. An edit box control sits over the OpenGL canvas. However, whenever the OpenGL canvas is redrawn, it obliterates the part of the edit box which sits above it, ignoring the specified window Z-order. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Having other windows interact with an OpenGL window is not a good idea. They don't interact well; it's best to keep child windows clear of OpenGL windows.